# select and remove table row

Tags: javascript, html

Stackoverflow contains several solutions to remove a HTML table row. But I couldn´t find a way where the user can select a row and delete this one, with the help of a button. I am trying to get this done but struggle with the selection.

Especially because the rows of myTable does not contain any id or tag. Even if I would add a tag, this must be known to remove this row. Any idea how to solve the puzzle?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Table Test</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #myTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #myTable td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    #delRow {
        width: auto;
        height: 30px;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <!-- filled by script -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="delRow">Del Row</button>

    <script>
        data = [
            {
                "property": "animal",
                "value": "dog"
            },
            {
                "property": "car",
                "value": "porsche"
            },
            {
                "property": "snacks",
                "value": "chips"
            }
        ]

        var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable")

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            var row = `<tr>
                        <td contenteditable="true">${data[i].property}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].value}</td>`

            myTable.innerHTML += row   
        }


        var delRow = document.getElementById("delRow")

        delRow.addEventListener("click", function() {
            //delete selected row
            console.log("delRow clicked")
        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _“where the user can select a row”_ - and how exactly is that supposed to happen?

Comment: You need to save the "state" of where the user clicked ( lets say some index ) and then when the user clicks on that button, the corresponding row will be removed.

Comment: @Wahalez thanks, which means I need to add a tag / index or any identifier. I hoped frontend languages where smart enough to notice the clicked row and create an temp identifier. Seems I need to do it manually.

Comment: _“ with the cursor, thats part of the question”_ - no, it was not part of the question, and that’s why I asked.

Comment: @ICoded Not necessarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep track of last clicked row e.g. in `lastClickedRow` variable and add listener switching the variable's value to each row.

It may not be the most effective option but it works.

```js
        data = [
            {
                "property": "animal",
                "value": "dog"
            },
            {
                "property": "car",
                "value": "porsche"
            },
            {
                "property": "snacks",
                "value": "chips"
            }
        ]

        var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable")

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            var row = `<tr>
                        <td contenteditable="true">${data[i].property}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].value}</td>`

            myTable.innerHTML += row   
        }


        var delRow = document.getElementById("delRow")
        let lastClickedRow = null
        for (var i = 0, row; row = myTable.rows[i]; i++) {
          row.addEventListener("click", function() {
            lastClickedRow = this
            console.log(lastClickedRow)
          })
        }
        delRow.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (lastClickedRow) {
              lastClickedRow.remove()
            }
            console.log("delRow clicked")
        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Table Test</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #myTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #myTable td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    #delRow {
        width: auto;
        height: 30px;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <!-- filled by script -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="delRow">Del Row</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thats exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Thank @Vulwsztyn for the solution. We might add a highlight to the last click row, so the user know which will be removed.

```js
        data = [
            {
                "property": "animal",
                "value": "dog"
            },
            {
                "property": "car",
                "value": "porsche"
            },
            {
                "property": "snacks",
                "value": "chips"
            }
        ]

        var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable")

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            var row = `<tr>
                        <td contenteditable="true">${data[i].property}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].value}</td>`

            myTable.innerHTML += row   
        }


        var delRow = document.getElementById("delRow")
        let lastClickedRow = null
        for (var i = 0, row; row = myTable.rows[i]; i++) {
          row.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if(lastClickedRow != null) {
              lastClickedRow.style.background = null
            }
            lastClickedRow = this
            lastClickedRow.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
            console.log(lastClickedRow)
          })
        }
        delRow.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (lastClickedRow) {
              lastClickedRow.remove()
            }
            console.log("delRow clicked")
        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Table Test</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #myTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #myTable td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    #delRow {
        width: auto;
        height: 30px;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <!-- filled by script -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="delRow">Del Row</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

the different way is add checkbox to rows:

```js
data = [
            {
                "property": "animal",
                "value": "dog"
            },
            {
                "property": "car",
                "value": "porsche"
            },
            {
                "property": "snacks",
                "value": "chips"
            }
        ]

        var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable")

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            var row = `<tr id="row-${i}">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">${data[i].property}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].value}</td>`

            myTable.innerHTML += row   
        }


        var delRow = document.getElementById("delRow")
        //delete selected row
        delRow.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
            var length = checkbox.length;
            if(length > 0){
                for(var i=0; i < length; i++){
                    if(checkbox[i].checked === true){
                        var rowname = "row-"+i;
                        //for remove rows
                        //document.getElementById(rowname).remove();
                        // for display=none
                        document.getElementById(rowname).style.display = 'none';
                        
                    }
                }
               
            }
            //console.log("delRow clicked")
        })
```

```css
 #myTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #myTable td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    #delRow {
        width: auto;
        height: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Table Test</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <!-- filled by script -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="delRow">Del Row</button>

</body>

</html>
```